# Replace value of cell in the sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I need a macro that takes the value in "I2" and replaces it everywhere in the Sheet with a spacebar "" then go to "I3" and does the same till ~"I6000" and if possible rotate through till "Z6000"IMPORTANT: If possible it should only delete the exact value so if there is a "5" it should only delete it where "5" is as a string alone not take "5675" and make it a "67"

Edit: I have more then 1 Value in 1 Cell Example: "ValueC ValueZ Value5 95 C-69"

I have this code:

```
Range("I2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Cells.Replace What:=I2, Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

How can I change it to go through "L2"-"Z6000"?

#### Example Screenshot excel with highlight

[image: Example Screenshot excel with highlight]

Comment: gotta love how this just gets downrated ... my english isnt that great im sorry if i cant explain it properly i try my best ...

Answer (score 1):

User following code it will do your job.

```
 Sub fillValue()

cellValue = Range("I2").Value

For i = 1 To 6000    'increase this value to add more rows
compareValue = Range("A" & i).Value
if compareValue = cellValue then
Range("A" & i).Value = ""
end if

compareValue = Range("B" & i).Value
if compareValue = cellValue then
Range("B" & i).Value = ""
end if


'Add as many column as you want.


Next
End Sub
```

In excel you can not assign single key to a macro. You have to assign it with the combination of Ctrl key as shown in following image.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, it tells me there is a syntax error sub fillValue() is filled in yellow and End sub() is marked red

Comment: I have updated the code. You only have to remove ....  I have placed these dots so you can add as many column as you want

Comment: Ehm now it worked, but it just filled the I2 Value everywhere i defined it , I need it to take the value in "I2" and replace/delete it anywhere in the Sheet sorry if my english isnt understandable enough D:

Comment: Question before i try this , does it delete exact values? Example:
in D95 i have "ValueC ValueD Value3 35 96 Value5"  if in in I2 is "5" will it turn my D95 to: "ValueC ValueD Value3 3 96 Value" ?

Comment: Your comment is not clear enough. Can put screen shots of these value with highlighting what you want so I can give you exact code which you required. Update your question and this screen shots into it.

Comment: i uploaded the screenshot

Comment: Thanks for posting screen shot. It will work as you have mentioned into your screen shot.

Comment: Please also tick my answer.

Comment: i said thank you because you said you will work on my problem, your answer isee isnt the answer to my problem

Comment: I mean this code will work fine for you post. You can test it in your spread sheet.